# APK version help required

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have uploaded an app on the Google PlayStore and since this is my first time so I am having confusions about uploading the new version. I have previous version already put there. When I upload the new APK do I need to deactivate the previous version straight away or wait for some time. What are the best practices.
Also, If I deactivate an APK, does it effect any current users? I just want that version to be stopped for being further installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You upload your APK to update/ replace the old one.

You do not create a new app page, nor do you need to deactivate the old one.

Any new users will install the new one, and existing users will be updated to the new one.

Note: those who do not update, will keep using the old version until they do update. There is no way to stop this. Nor should there be a need to

Comment: I am not creating a new page. I have uploaded a new version 1.1.1 but 1.0 is still there. I don't want 1.0 to be there. So I am thinking of deactivating it.
I am a bit noob in Android Development. Does the app gets updated automatically?

Comment: If they have it set to auto update apps, it will do. Else some users do it manually, or never bother at all! 1.0 should not be there anymore, the app page should show update 1.1.1 .

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to deactivate the old one. Since you upload the apk for the first time you can update it by changing the

```
android:versionCode="Z"
android:versionName="X.Y"
```

you have to be careful the the versionCode should be an incremental number. For example if the previous version has value 10, the next should have > 10. Then your application is automatically updated and the user is notified to update the application.

The reason you not always see the update in console, is that google play needs some time to be aware of the change.

Comment: Alright, I'll try this in my next build but some of the users were able to install the previous versions when they were available i.e. I have not deactivated them.